# Como consultar 4 tablas relacionadas entre si con ELOQUENT

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, datatables, eloquent

A partir de la tabla lista_principal trato de obtener 3 tablas relacionadas entre si, en este caso PROYECTOS-> TAREAS -> USERS lo estoy haciendo de esta forma y logro obtener los datos hasta la tabla tareas.

```
$lista_principal = Lista_principal::with('proyectos.tareas')
   ->orderBy('id', 'asc') ->get();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**MI INTENTO PARA TRAER TAMBIEN LA TABLA USERS LO CUAL ME DA ERROR DE LOGICA**

```
   $lista_principal = Lista_principal::with('proyectos.tareas.users')
       ->orderBy('id', 'asc') ->get();
```

**MODELO LISTA PRINCIPAL**

```
public function proyectos()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Proyectos');
}
```

**MODELO PROYECTOS**

```
public function tareas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tareas');

}

public function lista_principal()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Lista_principal');

}
```

**MODELO TAREAS**

```
public function proyectos()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Proyectos');
}


public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**MODELO USERS**

```
public function tareas()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Tareas');

}
```

Comment: hasta donde se, cuando vas a hacer uso de `eager loading` con múltiples relaciones, estas van en forma de array de este modo: `$book = Book::with(['editorial', 'author'])->get();`

Comment: Probe esto $lista_principal = Lista_principal::with(['proyectos.tareas', 'users'
])->orderBy('id', 'asc') ->get(); Y MED DIO ESTE ERROR  message: "Call to undefined relationship [users] on model [App\Lista_principal]."

Comment: Lo intente de esta forma $lista_principal = Lista_principal::with(['proyectos','tareas', 'users'
])->orderBy('id', 'asc') ->get();  y me da este error  message: "Call to undefined relationship [tareas] on model [App\Lista_principal]."

Comment: seguro que en cada modelo que ocupas, estan declaradas las relaciones necesarias?

Comment: si acabo de detallar los modelos a la pregunta puedes mirarla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**La solucion a este caso fue el codigo**

```
 $lista_principal = Lista_principal::with(['proyectos', 'proyectos.tareas', 
                                            'proyectos.tareas.users'])
                                    ->get();
```

Comment: recuerda que si esto fue la solución, entonces debes marcarla como respuesta aceptada

Comment: si, debo esperar dos dias al menos segun la plataforma

Comment: Puedes utilizar la función indicada anteriormente o realizar joins con la clase DB; Debes tener cuidado al consultar muchas tablas con with, que si bien es más sencillo, el rendimiento es más pobre (Por experiencia) y evita usar whereHas que igual ven afectado de forma notoria el rendimiento de la consulta cuando se trabaja con muchas tuplas o muchos joins. 
Si el rendimiento es primordial te aconsejo revisar como consultar con DB en la documentación de laravel y crear tus propios joins de forma más "cruda"

Comment: Quisiera hacer una pregunta a la respuesta presentada, si en algún nivel tienes un campo que hace referencia a otra tabla, me explico mejor, si en tareas tuvieses una columna tipo_id que hace referencia a un catalogo donde puede ser la tarea de tipo (cpresencial, no presencial) por ejemplo, como podrias recuperar ese dato explicativo (columna nombre) de este resulta en cualquier nivel... claro que ya tienes las referncias en los modelos igualmente...